# How can I share instantiated objects between methods?

Tags: java, object, methods

I have:

```
public class HFSim extends ApplicationTemplate
{
  private static  class AppFrame extends ApplicationTemplate.AppFrame 
 {
     void setBuoy()
        {
            //code
                Position buoypos=Position.fromDegrees(buoylat, buoylon);
        }
    void setVehicle()
        { 
           //code
           Position vehiclepos=Position.fromDegrees(lat, lon, elev);
        }

    double findDistance() 
        {
        //find distance between marker (vehicle) and a buoy
        Earth earth= new Earth();
        double radius = earth.getEquatorialRadius();

        double distancebetween=LatLon.ellipsoidalDistance(buoypos, vehiclepos, radius, 6356752.3); 
        return distancebetween;
        }
```

How can I use the objects buoypos and vehiclepos in the setBuoy and setVehicle methods in the findDistance() method?

Comment: To make it accessible, you'll have to make both objects `final` class-level variables; Trouble is, `final`: you can't reassign the variable in any case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two clearcut options here:

1. Make buoypos and vehiclepos instance variables, or..
2. Provide more descriptive names for setVehicle() and give it a `Position` return type.

Option 1 would look like this:

```
...classname...
{
    private Position vehiclePosition;
    private Position bouyPosition;

    public void setVehiclePosition()
    {
        this.vehiclePosition = ....
    }
}
```

Option 2 would look like this:

```
...classname...
{
    public Position createVehiclePosition()
    {
        vehiclePosition = ....
        return vehiclePosition.
    }
}
```

Finally, you would use them as either:

```
...classname...
{
    public double findDistance()
    {
        ...this.vehiclePosition...
        or
        Position vehiclePos = this.createVehiclePosition();
    }
}
```

The option you choose is highly dependent on how the class is supposed to behave.

Comment: If vehiclePosition is not a int or double, can it still be returned like in Option 2?

Comment: The example I posted was for reference types (i.e. objects i.e not ints or doubles). If you meant "will it also work for primitive types?", then yes it will.

Answer (score 0):

Use variables with the class [scope](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/intro-to-oop-java-scope-rules/). This essentially means

```
 ///outside of a method but within the class you'll want to set:
 private this.bouypos = new Position;
 private this vehiclepos = new Position;
 //method1 {
 Position this.buoypos=Position.fromDegrees(buoylat, buoylon);
 //method2 {
 Position this.vehiclepos=Position.fromDegrees(lat, lon, elev);
//method3 calls things set in method1 & 2
 findDistance(){
     //code
     double distancebetween=LatLon.ellipsoidalDistance(this.buoypos, this.vehiclepos, radius, 6356752.3); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the findDistance method take two Positions as parameters

```
double findDistance(Position buoypos, Position vehiclepos){

}
```

Comment: But if I call `this.findDistance()` within the class constructor, won't it want the same parameters for the constructor?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I need more information to help